# Science fiction fantasy manga in which the main character can transport himself back and forth between two worlds

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This is a **science fiction fantasy** manga where the main character can transport himself to another world (back and forth). The time difference is probably one week in the other world to one day for his world. In this story the main character gets a **"3 year head start"** from the rest of the people before they can go in or even know what it is. This main character may or may not have memories from the future. (I don't remember.)

In this other world, he starts out with nothing (probably) and has to survive till he is suddenly saved by a few cultivators: a ***beautiful general girl and a male general (young female and older male)*** fighting off monsters. They were on the brink of death until the master of them kills the monster and so they are saved and prompted to bring the suspicious boy back. Long story short: he takes her as his master and learns from them till he meets with the game-like screen once again to go to his original world.

Little do we know that he is bringing his powers in the original of advanced technology with martial artist with supernatural abilities reside. He isn't all that powerful, compared with the top powerhouse royal or higher-up **officials (the citizens don't have the powers because higher ups regulate it)**. He then out of no where asks the AI to promote him and shows her a mech suit blueprint from the future.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the main character? Also, can you be clearer about the level of technology in the two worlds? It sounds like at least one of them had advanced technology. Was that the main character's original world? And was the other world more primitive, like ancient China?